# Make a player move towards the direction he is facing (Unity3D/C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

Right now I have a small soldier on the screen that moves with W, A, S, D and rotates / changes direction with the arrow keys. What I want to happen is when the player's direction changes (by using the arrow keys), pushing W will send him in that direction instead of up the screen.

Also (for example), if you are holding D and the right arrow key at the same time he should move in a circle about a point on the ground (instead of spinning in a circle while moving in a straight line to the right).

Here is my current code:

```
public class MovePlayer : MonoBehaviour {
  void Update() {
    // Rotate left
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
      transform.Rotate(0, 0, 1.3f);
    }
    // Rotate right
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
      transform.Rotate(0, 0, -1.3f);
    }
    // Strafe left
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) { 
  Vector3 position = this.transform.position;
      position.x -= 0.055f;
      this.transform.position = position;
    }
    // Move up      
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W)) {
      Vector3 position = this.transform.position;
        position.y += 0.043f;
        this.transform.position = position;
    } 
    // Move down        
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S)) {
      Vector3 position = this.transform.position;
      position.y -= 0.043f;
      this.transform.position = position;
      isMoving = true;
    }
    // Strafe right     
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) {
      Vector3 position = this.transform.position;
      position.x += 0.055f;
      this.transform.position = position;
    } 
}
```

}

Any ideas? Wasn't sure what to search exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've done for my character (Plus a mouse script for directions)

```
update()
{
        Vector3 dir = new Vector3(); //(0,0,0)
        //float CharacterSpeed = 10.0f;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            dir.z += 1.0f;
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            dir.x -= 1.0f;
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
            dir.z -= 1.0f;
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            dir.x += 1.0f;

        dir.Normalize();
        transform.Translate(dir * CharacterSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

If you only have keyboard for movement : (I'm not %100 sure this one)

```
        Vector3 dir = new Vector3(); //(0,0,0)
        //float CharacterSpeed = 10.0f;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            dir.z += 1.0f;
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            var Rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis("Rotation Angle Here", transform.InverseTransformDirection(Vector3.up));
            transform.localRotation *= Rotation;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
            dir.z -= 1.0f;
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            {
            var Rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis("Rotation Angle Here", transform.InverseTransformDirection(Vector3.up));
            transform.localRotation *= Rotation;
        }

        dir.Normalize();
        transform.Translate(dir * CharacterSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I don't want my arrow keys and WASD to do the same things, I want my arrow keys to rotate the player whereas WASD actually move him up down right and left. The problem is that the up, down, right and left direction that he moves in should be relative to where he is facing instead of the world. I have tried to add the lines var Rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis("Rotation Angle Here", transform.InverseTransformDirection(Vector3.up)); and
            transform.localRotation *= Rotation; to my W event but right now he just rotates inwards. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Well than you can merge the two code that I gave you. For rotation, you should give inverse values for left and right. (eg. 5.0f , -5.0f).  For W and S keys rotation, change Quaternion second parameter to "Vector3.right" instead of up vector.

Comment: Ok I tried this - but the player still rotates inwards when I press W A S D. If I keep holding W for instance there will be a point where you can't see the player anymore (I guess he is being rotated around the z axis?). I forgot to mention that my game is 2D

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Transform.forward`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html) to get the **facing direction in world space**, then simply scale, and add up to the current `position`. Just hook up this to **W**:

`this.transform.position += this.transform.forward * 0.043f;`